# How to export from Digikam to Google+

Tags: photo-management, google-picasa, photography, digikam, google-plus

[Digikam](http://www.digikam.org) is an excellent photo management program which has built in support to easily export images to PicassaWeb. Picassa is now owned by Google, who are deprecating it in favour of Google Plus.

How can we easily use Digikam to export to Google Plus? (Google+)

Answer (score 0):

The 'Export to Picasa Web' service will upload photos to Google+ Photos.

Once you enter your login details, when choosing to upload, you'll see your Google+ photo folders in the Album drop down.

Creating new albums works too.